# Traffic stats resets on boot

Tags: android, network-traffic

Hi I am trying to get usage of each android application by using below code.

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> applist = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
    Iterator<PackageInfo> it = applist.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        PackageInfo pk = (PackageInfo) it.next();
        if (pk.versionName == null) {
            continue ;
        }
        double received = (double) TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(pk.applicationInfo.uid)

                / (1024 * 1024);
        double send = (double) TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(pk.applicationInfo.uid)
                / (1024 * 1024);
        double total = received + send;
        textview.setText(pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                                    getActivity().getPackageManager())
                                    .toString() + " " +String.format( "%.2f", total )+" MB");
    }
```

But if the device is restarted then the values are getting deleted.  But in Device if you go Android Setting -> Data usage ->  The usage still exists. My Question is

> from where to read data usage of each application. ?

Code explanation is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: did you find solution to this

Comment: I didn't found any :(

Answer (score 0):

TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(int) will only return data usage from device boot. Why don't you try writing the traffic data to file, so that it will be available after boot? You can build a START_REDELIVER_INTENT service to run in background

Comment: UID is not permanent for apps. it will get changed by the system if it is not most active or any other algorithms which was done in android. but if you see nexus or any 4.4.4 + device usage you could get all data usage of each app from even past months.

Comment: @Fabin Paul How to get saved data after boot per day.